# Lambda authorizer response using async/await in Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a lambda authorizer on aws using node.js async/await instead of callbacks but there is no information on how to create the HTTP response returned to API Gateway. For example, if i return this :

```
{
  statusCode: 401
}
```

the API gateway doesn't seem to understand and return an error 403 to the client :

```
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "No principalId set on the Response"
}
```

Does anyone knows how to do what is described here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html
but using async / await ?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :**

The way to return an error 401 is simply to throw an error like this :
`throw new Error("Unauthorized")`
And if the user is explicitly deny / allow, simply return the JSON policy.

Comment: Can you put here some code please, to try to help you, please?

Comment: If you figured it out on your own, you are allowed to answer your own questions :) .

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Using the callback causes warnings but I would rather use async/await without the cb.

Comment: @Chance The solution is in the "Edit" section in my post. You simply have to throw an Error with "Unauthorized" as message. I added an answer to my own question so it will be more visible.

Comment: @julient-monisnap thanks :). Simple enough!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To return a 401 error you simply need to throw an error with "Unauthorized" as message, like this :

```js
throw new Error("Unauthorized")
```

And if the user is explicitly deny / allow, simply return the JSON policy like you would do with callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

I think the accepted solution does not work (anymore). I tried it like this:

```js
exports.authorize = async (event, context) => {
  throw new Error("Unauthorized")
}
```

It works but in my logs I can see this error:

`ERROR    Invoke Error    {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Unauthorized","stack":["Error: Unauthorized","    at Runtime.exports.authorize [as handler] (/var/task/handler/auth.js:21:13)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"]}`

Comment: Do you use it inside a lambda authorizer (not a regular lambda) ? And which version of node.js do you use ?

Comment: Yes, authorizer lambda. I'm using Node 12.x.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read (some code samples would be helpful) it sounds like you're not calling the callback right or it's not called in the right place. You can use

`callback("Some error message.");`

to send back a response w/ a 401 status code. You can also change this by doing something like:

```
var response = {
  statusCode: 401, /* some number */        
  body: "Oops!" /* some message */
}; 
callback(null, response);
```

I would check out [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html) page for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i don't want to use callbacks. I found a way to do it and will edit my post.